# ComboBox in java if statement

Tags: java

I studied ComboBox topic today but I didn't understand this if statement in the code. How this if statements works. kindly explain it.

```
class ItemChangeListener implements ItemListener{
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
       if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          Object item = event.getItem();
          // do something with object
       }
    }       
}
```

Comment: There are multiple itemState changes, thats what the if command filters out: you only care about the selection of a combo box. For that kind of event the actual selected item is `event.getItem()`.

Answer (score 2):

When you change the selection in an `ComboBox`, `itemStateChanged` is fired twice: first time for the item that gets deselected (`event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED`), second time for the item that gets selected (`event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED`).

In other words, the `if` is required to check if `item` is the current selection or the old one.

Answer (score 0):

The `itemStateChanged` method will be called any time the state of an item in the combo box changes.

The if statement, `if (event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {` is checking to see what exactly changed. It is checking if the change was that an item was selected.

Then, inside the if statement block, once the code has determined that an item was indeed selected, the code proceeds to determine which item was actually selected.

This code is demonstrating how a change in selection inside the combo box can be handled by your code, and it would be expected that your custom code would do something more relevant to your application when the item is selected.